# Rails form input fields overflowing with Bootstrap 3 modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the `simple_form` gem to make a form in a modal dialog. The issue is that the input fields go over the edge of the modal.

[image]

The code cascades as follows: `index.html.erb`

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="cold-md-2">
    <%= link_to "New Author", new_author_path, remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary"%>
 </div>
 <div id="author-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog"></div>
</div>
```

`new.js.erb`

```
 $('#author-modal').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'new') %>');
 $('#author-modal').modal('show');
```

`_new.html.erb`

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Author</h4>
        <%= render 'form'%>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and lastly `_form.html.erb`

```
 <%= simple_form_for @author, remote: true, html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f|%>
 <div class="modal-body">
<ul class="errors"></ul>
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :first_name %>
    <%= f.input :last_name %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"}%>
</div>

 <% end %>
```

why isn't the bootstrap default 100% width for form items limited to the modal?

Comment: Can you share the css for `modal-* ` classes in the question.

Comment: standard bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Can you create a js-fiddle with the raw source code of generated HTML.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WYrP8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the view as below,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :first_name, input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
    <%= f.input :title, input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
</div>
```

For `width: 100%`, you should use `form-control` class for the input controls.

Refer to **[Forms Basic Example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example)**

> Individual form controls automatically receive some global styling.
>   All textual `<input>, <textarea>, and <select>` elements with
>   .form-control are set to width: 100%; by default.

Comment: Glad to help. :) This fits with Bootstrap philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

I overwrode the bootstrap_config.css.scss with:

`input{ width:100%;}` and it solves it.